# how to access privacy protection pin -ausus mobile

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I forgot my pin. It has considered as theft when I changed my SIM card.Now I want to access my mobile-AUSUS mobile.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is enter recovery mode and do a full wipe/factory reset. You will lose all your data but it will unlock your phone. The instruction to perform the reset can be found online easily.

If you plan to ask how to unlock without deleting everything - unless you have USB debugging enabled and root - there is no way.